# How to use Views to make slideshow of the content created using block type

Tags: views, entities, nodes, javascript

To Explain further:

Please I have created a block content type directly from block, say Item_1 using ADD BLOCK then published. I did the same 3twice (item_2,item_3) each carries its contents(body). all published.
Now I want to use views to view this block type via slideshow method. Could this be possible?

All I saw in the filter list of views 3 version are all nodes, content types none points to this.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to create a View from Blocks? It's not possible as far as I know, and it's not really a good idea I think. You could instead create a new Content Type (Structure -> Content Types), and add each of your block's contents into a separate node of the type you made.

Then use Views to create a node view, filtered by the Content Type you created. You can then display this view as a Block, with a "Slideshow" display style using the [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module

Comment: Thank u Baysaa for your prompt reply. I did that for the other content type i created using add content i presume that were node oriented. but in this case, i av already created this items and published. Could it be that views are only used for node items created via cck? please help

Comment: No, Views can be used for normal Nodes without any additional CCK fields. Node module is Drupal's core content module, CCK module extends Node module with additional fields like an Image field or Select list field etc. I don't mean to be nasty or mean, but I think you should read up a bit on Nodes and Blocks, because I think you're mixing them up a bit. I still don't understand your original question, and your comment just confused me more :)